# Git Extensions GUI: set source code language for "colorization"?

Tags: plugins, git-extensions

I'm working with a repository of MATLAB code in git (company internal repo) using the "GitExtensions" app.  The displayed code in the "FileTree" window is colorized more or less as though it were c-language code.   Is there any way to specify other languages, similar to how  Notepad++ does?

Comment: This is something you should be asking at the project's GitHub repo.